# C++ what is after the function signature

Tags: c++

```
StaticEquilibriumConstraint::StaticEquilibriumConstraint(
    const MultibodyPlant<AutoDiffXd>* plant,
    systems::Context<AutoDiffXd>* context,
    const std::map<SortedPair<geometry::GeometryId>,
                   GeometryPairContactWrenchEvaluatorBinding>&
        contact_pair_to_wrench_evaluator)
    : solvers::Constraint(plant->num_velocities(),
                          plant->num_positions() + plant->num_actuated_dofs() +
                              GetLambdaSize(contact_pair_to_wrench_evaluator),
                          Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(plant->num_velocities()),
                          Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(plant->num_velocities())),
      plant_{plant},
      context_{context},
      contact_pair_to_wrench_evaluator_(contact_pair_to_wrench_evaluator),
      B_actuation_{plant_->MakeActuationMatrix()} {}
```

What is the bit of code that starts with ":solvers::Constraint"? What is that called in C++

It is NOT an initializer list, because no variables are declared after the colon. So please, do not link me to that question.

Comment: The linked question does NOT answer my question.

Comment: There is no assignment happening in the code snippet I posted

Comment: Why do you think this isn't the constructor initializer list? (It is)

Comment: @user3180 It is a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). It just so happens to contain a delegated constructor call, which may be the part that's confusing things.

Comment: In the previous question, the syntax was var(assignment_variable), and it essentially did var = assignment_variable.

Comment: I guess Constraint(*inputs) doesn't look like that. There is no target variable we are assigning to (like "var").

Comment: I also don't understand what is the point of creating all these variables like plant_ if the body is empty {}. What do we even do with these initialized variables?

Comment: This ***is*** an initializer list. You are initializing the base class by calling its constructor. See [[class.base.init](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.base.init)] in the language standard.